# Google BigQuery Server to server authorization fails

Tags: oauth, google-bigquery

Trying to authorize access to Google BigQuery with "Server to server authorization" described [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization). My certificate.p12 and ServiceAccountId are set properly. But I constantly get an exception:

```
 com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(Ljava/io/OutputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Lcom/google/api/client/json/JsonGenerator;
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(Ljava/io/OutputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Lcom/google/api/client/json/JsonGenerator;
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.toByteStream(JsonFactory.java:187)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.toByteArray(JsonFactory.java:157)
at com.google.api.client.auth.jsontoken.RsaSHA256Signer.sign(RsaSHA256Signer.java:51)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:313)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:505)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:266)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:888)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.execute(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:181)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClient.executeUnparsed(GoogleClient.java:243)
at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest.executeUnparsed(JsonHttpRequest.java:209)
at com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Datasets$List.execute(Bigquery.java:1339)
at model.BigQuery$.addEvent(BigQuery.scala:109)


java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(Ljava/io/OutputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Lcom/google/api/client/json/JsonGenerator;
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.toByteStream(JsonFactory.java:187) ~[google-http-client-1.13.1-beta.jar:1.13.1-beta]
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.toByteArray(JsonFactory.java:157) ~[google-http-client-1.13.1-beta.jar:1.13.1-beta]
at com.google.api.client.auth.jsontoken.RsaSHA256Signer.sign(RsaSHA256Signer.java:51) ~[google-oauth-client-1.13.1-beta.jar:1.13.1-beta]
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:313) ~[google-api-client-1.13.2-beta.jar:1.13.2-beta]
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:505) ~[google-oauth-client-1.13.1-beta.jar:1.13.1-beta]
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:266) ~[google-oauth-client-1.13.1-beta.jar:1.13.1-beta]
```

is there any ideas why this happens?

Thanks.

UPD: After update google libs to 1.14.1-beta everything works fine

Comment: Dmitry, can you add your "UPD: After update google libs to 1.14.1-beta everything works fine" so that I can mark it as an official answer (and give you some points?) :-)

Comment: didn't get where do you want me to put this UPD... Add as a comment?

Comment: Ha, no I mean, add this statement to the "Your Answer" box below :-)

Answer (score 0):

After update google libs to 1.14.1-beta everything works fine